# C# merging 3 numbers through bitwise operators / bitshift

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I started off with a 16 bit number that represents 3 different colours in the RGB565 format. I managed to split it up into 3 seperate sets of bits (red, green, and blue). I've now made changes to the bits and have the variables vRed, vGreen, and vBlue. How do I merge them together into a single 16 bit number again?

Comment: Is the opposite of the extraction not obvious?

Comment: **show code**  *Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://SSCCE.org) for guidance.*

Comment: If you mask and shift to break apart, you would shift the same amounts in the opposite directions and OR the three components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
int rgb565 = vBlue | (vGreen << 5) | (vRed << 11);
```

or

```
int rgb565 = (((vRed << 6) | vGreen) << 5) | vBlue;
```

You could cast that to `ushort` afterwards, if desired.